# How to get config data from a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, file, module, linux-kernel, config

I'm working on a module in the Linux kernel that needs access to a configuration file containing some basic text values.

Problem is, I read that it's a no-no to read files from within the kernel. [This article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110) says to "use sysfs files within a kernel module" - problem is I'm not sure what that means.

I need something dirt simple. Does anyone know how I can create a custom config file for my custom module and read it in at runtime?

I'm working with Linux kernel 3.12.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need dirt simple, then pass parameters to the module on the `insmod`/`modprobe` command line.

To see how to declare parameters, look at other people's modules.

(To do anything in a module that other people's modules already do, look at other people's modules, including how to register into sysfs.)

If the configuration can change at runtime, while the module stays inserted, then you can't use module parameters for it.